# Western Digital Elements not recognized

Tags: hard-drive

I'm trying to connect my existing external [drive](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136540) to the Raspberry Pi.  I'm using the powered [USB hub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005C32NMS) to connect it.  Here is my dmesg

```
[ 6425.856037] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6425.856068] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.856081] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6425.856094] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.856104] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6425.856122] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.856134] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6425.856147] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6425.856155] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6425.858289] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6425.858318] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.858331] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6425.858344] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.858354] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6425.858373] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.858384] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6425.858398] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6425.858407] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 38 00 00 08 00
[ 6425.860536] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6425.860565] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.860579] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6425.860593] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.860602] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6425.860621] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.860633] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6425.860713] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6425.860730] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6425.862907] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6425.862938] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.862952] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6425.862965] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.862975] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6425.862994] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.863006] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6425.863058] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6425.863070] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6425.915809] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6425.915848] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.915861] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6425.915875] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.915885] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6425.915907] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.915917] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6425.915931] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6425.915940] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6425.922933] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6425.922969] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.922983] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6425.922997] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.923007] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6425.923029] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.923039] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6425.923053] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6425.923062] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6425.925302] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6425.925338] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.925351] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6425.925365] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.925374] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6425.925396] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6425.925406] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6425.925420] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6425.925429] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6635.928565] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6635.928604] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.928618] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6635.928632] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.928642] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6635.928663] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.928675] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6635.928689] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6635.928699] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6635.928735] blk_update_request: 144 callbacks suppressed
[ 6635.928747] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 6635.928761] quiet_error: 144 callbacks suppressed
[ 6635.928774] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 6635.931543] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6635.931606] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.931623] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6635.931637] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.931647] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6635.931666] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.931708] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6635.931726] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6635.931737] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6635.931773] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 6635.931790] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 6635.936936] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6635.936971] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.936984] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6635.936997] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.937006] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6635.937026] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.937036] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6635.937052] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6635.937061] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00
[ 6635.937098] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 6635.937115] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 6635.937149] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 1
[ 6635.937166] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 2
[ 6635.937183] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 3
[ 6635.939073] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6635.939104] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.939116] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6635.939129] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.939139] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6635.939158] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.939168] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6635.939183] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6635.939191] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6635.939228] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 6635.939245] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 6635.941575] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6635.941608] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.941621] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6635.941634] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.941644] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6635.941663] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.941675] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6635.941689] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6635.941699] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 74 70 57 f8 00 00 01 00
[ 6635.941738] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 19
[ 6635.941757] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 24418995
[ 6635.943830] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6635.943860] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.943872] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6635.943885] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.943894] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6635.943913] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.943925] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6635.943938] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6635.943946] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 74 70 57 f8 00 00 01 00
[ 6635.943986] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 19
[ 6635.944004] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 24418995
[ 6635.947088] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6635.947116] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.947128] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6635.947141] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.947150] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6635.947172] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.947182] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6635.947196] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6635.947205] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00
[ 6635.947242] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 6635.947259] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 6635.949336] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6635.949370] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.949384] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6635.949397] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.949407] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6635.949429] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6635.949439] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6635.949452] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6635.949461] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6635.949497] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 6855.992089] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6855.992129] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6855.992142] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6855.992156] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6855.992165] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6855.992186] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6855.992198] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6855.992212] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6855.992221] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6855.992258] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 6855.992273] quiet_error: 4 callbacks suppressed
[ 6855.992287] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 6855.995200] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6855.995234] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6855.995246] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6855.995260] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6855.995270] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6855.995368] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6855.995387] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6855.995404] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6855.995414] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6855.995453] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 6855.995471] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 6856.000362] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6856.000402] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.000415] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6856.000429] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.000439] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6856.000462] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.000473] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6856.000487] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6856.000497] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00
[ 6856.000535] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 6856.000553] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 6856.000589] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 1
[ 6856.000607] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 2
[ 6856.000622] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 3
[ 6856.002723] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6856.002757] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.002771] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6856.002784] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.002793] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6856.002814] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.002826] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6856.002840] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6856.002849] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6856.002885] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 6856.002902] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 6856.005840] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6856.005868] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.005881] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6856.005894] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.005904] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6856.005924] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.005933] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6856.005948] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6856.005957] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 74 70 57 f8 00 00 01 00
[ 6856.005997] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 19
[ 6856.006015] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 24418995
[ 6856.008099] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6856.008131] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.008144] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6856.008157] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.008166] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6856.008186] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.008198] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6856.008212] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6856.008221] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 74 70 57 f8 00 00 01 00
[ 6856.008260] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 19
[ 6856.008278] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 24418995
[ 6856.011363] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6856.011394] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.011407] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6856.011420] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.011430] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6856.011453] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.011463] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6856.011477] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6856.011486] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00
[ 6856.011523] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0
[ 6856.011541] Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
[ 6856.013608] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[ 6856.013641] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.013654] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[ 6856.013667] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.013676] Sense Key : 0x7 [current]
[ 6856.013698] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
[ 6856.013708] ASC=0x74 ASCQ=0x71
[ 6856.013722] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[ 6856.013730] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 6856.013767] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0
```

and less /var/log/messages | grep sda

```
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.793302] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.793328] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.793356] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.793381] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.795528] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.802313] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.802338] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.802367] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.802392] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.804530] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.804559] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.804584] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.804613] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.804637] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.806784] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.806811] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.806837] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.806865] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.806890] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.809163] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.809194] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.809220] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.809257] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.809283] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.812784] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.812812] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.812837] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.812867] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.812892] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.815058] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.815090] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.815116] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.815184] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.815211] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.817393] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.817423] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.817448] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.817478] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.817503] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.819644] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.819676] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.819701] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.819729] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.819753] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.822030] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.822060] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.822085] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.822114] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.822139] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.824278] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.824306] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.824332] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.824361] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.824387] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.826530] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.826561] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.826587] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.826615] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.826641] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.828770] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.828803] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.828829] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.828858] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.828883] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.831047] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.835810] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.835837] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.835867] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.835892] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.838020] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.838053] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.838079] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.838107] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.838133] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.840271] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.840303] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.840330] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.840359] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.840384] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.842654] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.842687] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.842713] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.842743] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.842768] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.845042] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.845074] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.845100] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.845130] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.845154] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.847271] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.847303] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.847328] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.847357] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.847382] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.849523] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.849555] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.849581] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.849610] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.849635] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.851520] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.851550] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.851576] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.851605] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.851629] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.853786] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.853818] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.853843] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.853871] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.853896] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.856037] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.856068] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.856094] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.856122] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.856147] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.858289] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.858318] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.858344] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.858373] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.858398] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.860536] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.862938] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.862965] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.862994] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.863058] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.915809] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.915848] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.915875] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.915907] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.915931] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.922933] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.922969] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.922997] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.923029] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.923053] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.925302] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.925338] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.925365] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.925396] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:40:14 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6425.925420] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.928565] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.928604] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.928632] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.928663] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.928689] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.931543] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.931606] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.931637] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.931666] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.931726] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.936936] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.936971] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.936997] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.937026] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.937052] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.939073] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.939104] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.939129] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.939158] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.939183] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.941575] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.941608] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.941634] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.941663] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.941689] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.943830] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.943860] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.943885] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.943913] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.943938] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.947088] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.947116] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.947141] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.947172] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.947196] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.949336] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.949370] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.949397] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.949429] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:43:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6635.949452] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6855.992089] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6855.992129] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6855.992156] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6855.992186] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6855.992212] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6855.995200] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6855.995234] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6855.995260] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6855.995368] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6855.995404] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.000362] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.005868] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.005894] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.005924] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.005948] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.008099] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.008131] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.008157] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.008186] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.008212] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.011363] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.011394] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.011420] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.011453] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.011477] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.013608] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled s
ense code
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.013641] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.013667] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.013698] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]
Jan 13 19:47:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 6856.013722] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

Anyone know why I can't get the drive to show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to fix it by powering the Pi from the same hub as the drive.